# How do we add aligned equations in lyx . (For IEEE Transaction document)?

Tags: math-mode, equations, lyx

How do we add aligned equations in lyx . (For IEEE Transaction document)?

There is no option for insert -> math -> numbered equations. Moreover how do align the equation just like we do in latex using '&'

Currently I'm writing the equations in Latex and then adding it to Lyx using Tex Mode. is there a better way to do this?

**Edit** : 
I actually need something like this

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}a & =5 \\ = 7-2 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

But the latex source of LyX gives me something like this:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}a & =5\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned} & =6-1\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

How can I correct this? Should I use multiline AMS?
I couldn't find an option to add row. can you please tell the exact steps.

Answer (score 6):

Look just a little bit further down the Insert --> Math menu, and you'll find for example *AMS align environment*, which inserts an `align` environment from `amsmath`.

So you say you want `aligned` inside `equation`. The steps for that will be:

1. Insert --> Math --> Numbered Formula.

   (Or you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> to insert an unnumbered displayed equation, and then hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> to turn it into a numbered one.)
2. Insert --> Math --> Aligned environment. Now you should have something like this:

   [image]

   (The first blue box should contain the stuff left of `&`, the second box the stuff right of `&`, in LaTeX code.)
3. To add a new row here, do one of the following:

   1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> when the cursor is at the end of the last cell in the row.
   2. Click the *Add row* button in the math toolbar, which looks like this:

      [image]
   3. Or use the corresponding keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd>

If you want `align` instead `equation`+`aligned`, so that every line is numbered, skip step 1, and choose *AMS align environment* instead of *Aligned environment*. Or, if you insert a standard numbered equation, and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will be converted to an `align` environment automatically.

Comment: Did you mean AMS align environment? I tried that . it allows only two lines of equations

Comment: I thought of adding screenshot. But I'm not able to . as the option dissappear as soon as I click screenshot button

Comment: @DheerajMPai It supports more, but you need to add new rows yourself. There is a button on the toolbar, and it's probably available via right clicking as well.

Comment: I tried that. I actually need something like this

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}a & =5 \\ = 7-2 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

But it gives me something lke this:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}a & =5\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned} & =6-1\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

How can I correct this? Should I use multiline AMS?
I couldn't find an option to add row. can you please tell the exact steps.

Comment: I have included the above comment in the question in a better formatted form. Sorry for bothering you repeatedely @Torbjorn T

Comment: @DheerajMPai Same way you add rows to a table I think. Not at my computer now, will edit in a few hours.

Comment: @DheerajMPai See if my edit made it clearer.